# 'if' in prolog?

Tags: prolog, iso-prolog, logical-purity

Is there a way to do an if in prolog, e.g. if a variable is 0, then to do some actions (write text to the terminal). An else isn't even needed, but I can't find any documentation of if.

Comment: See [if-then-else](http://www.learnprolognow.org/) from www.learnprolognow.org

Comment: Prolog has a builtin `if-then-else` syntax. But it is not declarative to really use it.

Comment: `myFunc(Variable) :- Variable=0,print('OK, here is your text.').`

Answer (score 56, accepted):

A standard prolog predicate will do this.

```
   isfive(5).
```

will evaluate to true if you call it with 5 and fail(return false) if you run it with anything else.  For not equal you use \=

```
isNotEqual(A,B):- A\=B.
```

Technically it is does not unify, but it is similar to not equal.

[Learn Prolog Now is a good website for learning prolog.](http://www.learnprolognow.org/)

Edit:
To add another example.

```
isEqual(A,A).
```

Comment: +1 for enforcing logic programming style instead of imperative one :-)

Answer (score 117):

Yes, there is such a control construct in ISO Prolog, called `->`.  You use it like this:

```
( condition -> then_clause ; else_clause )
```

Here is an example that uses a chain of else-if-clauses:

```
(   X < 0 ->
    writeln('X is negative.  That's weird!  Failing now.'),
    fail
;   X =:= 0 ->
    writeln('X is zero.')
;   writeln('X is positive.')
)
```

Note that if you omit the else-clause, the condition failing will mean that the whole if-statement will fail.  Therefore, I recommend always including the else-clause (even if it is just `true`).

Comment: In ISO, the control construct is actually called (;)/2 - if-then-else (7.8.8) because the principal functor is the (;)/2.  This is a bit irritating since there is another control construct with the same principal functor: (;)/2 - disjunction (7.8.6). You can see it like this `(if->then;else) == ((if->then);else).` succeeds.

Answer (score 33):

Prolog predicates 'unify' -

So, in an imperative langauge I'd write

```
function bazoo(integer foo)
{
   if(foo == 5)
       doSomething();
   else
       doSomeOtherThing();
}
```

In Prolog I'd write

```
bazoo(5) :-  doSomething.
bazoo(Foo) :- Foo =/= 5, doSomeOtherThing.
```

which, when you understand both styles, is actually a lot clearer.
"I'm bazoo for the special case when foo is 5"
"I'm bazoo for the normal case when foo isn't 5"

Comment: `bazoo(5+0)` fails silently, whereas `bazoo(5+1)` does some other thing

Comment: @false it probably should do the negation of `Foo is 5` if you want it to simplify numbers like that.

Comment: @ProQ: That would be `dif(Foo, 5)`

Comment: This helped a ton with how to think about the difference between the two styles of programming. Cheers.

Answer (score 19):

First, let's recall some classical first order logic:

> "*If* P *then* Q *else* R" is equivalent to "(P *and* Q) *or* (non_P *and* R)".

---

#### How can we express "if-then-else" like *that* in Prolog?

Let's take the following concrete example:

> *If* `X` is a member of list `[1,2]` *then* `X` equals `2` *else* `X` equals `4`.

We can match above pattern ("*If* P *then* Q *else* R") if ...

- condition `P` is `list_member([1,2],X)`,
- negated condition `non_P` is `non_member([1,2],X)`,
- consequence `Q` is `X=2`, and
- alternative `R` is `X=4`.

To express list (non-)membership in a pure way, we define:

```
list_memberd([E|Es],X) :-
   (  E = X
   ;  dif(E,X),
      list_memberd(Es,X)
   ).

non_member(Es,X) :-
   maplist(dif(X),Es).
```

---

Let's check out different ways of expressing "if-then-else" in Prolog!

1. `(P,Q ; non_P,R)`

   ```
   ?-      (list_memberd([1,2],X), X=2 ; non_member([1,2],X), X=4).
   X = 2 ; X = 4.
   ?- X=2, (list_memberd([1,2],X), X=2 ; non_member([1,2],X), X=4), X=2.
   X = 2 ; false.
   ?-      (list_memberd([1,2],X), X=2 ; non_member([1,2],X), X=4), X=2.
   X = 2 ; false.
   ?- X=4, (list_memberd([1,2],X), X=2 ; non_member([1,2],X), X=4), X=4.
   X = 4.
   ?-      (list_memberd([1,2],X), X=2 ; non_member([1,2],X), X=4), X=4.
   X = 4.
   ```

   Correctness score 5/5. Efficiency score 3/5.
2. `(P -> Q ; R)`

   ```
   ?-      (list_memberd([1,2],X) -> X=2 ; X=4).
   false.                                                % WRONG
   ?- X=2, (list_memberd([1,2],X) -> X=2 ; X=4), X=2.
   X = 2.
   ?-      (list_memberd([1,2],X) -> X=2 ; X=4), X=2.
   false.                                                % WRONG
   ?- X=4, (list_memberd([1,2],X) -> X=2 ; X=4), X=4.
   X = 4.
   ?-      (list_memberd([1,2],X) -> X=2 ; X=4), X=4.
   false.                                                % WRONG
   ```

   Correctness score 2/5. Efficiency score 2/5.
3. `(P *-> Q ; R)`

   ```
   ?-      (list_memberd([1,2],X) *-> X=2 ; X=4).
   X = 2 ; false.                                        % WRONG
   ?- X=2, (list_memberd([1,2],X) *-> X=2 ; X=4), X=2.
   X = 2 ; false.
   ?-      (list_memberd([1,2],X) *-> X=2 ; X=4), X=2.
   X = 2 ; false.
   ?- X=4, (list_memberd([1,2],X) *-> X=2 ; X=4), X=4.
   X = 4.
   ?-      (list_memberd([1,2],X) *-> X=2 ; X=4), X=4.
   false.                                                % WRONG
   ```

   Correctness score 3/5. Efficiency score 1/5.

---

(Preliminary) summary:

1. `(P,Q ; non_P,R)` is correct, but needs a discrete implementation of `non_P`.
2. `(P -> Q ; R)` loses declarative semantics when instantiation is insufficient.
3. `(P *-> Q ; R)` is "less" incomplete than `(P -> Q ; R)`, but still has similar woes.

---

Luckily for us, there *are* alternatives:
**Enter the logically monotone control construct `if_/3`!**

We can use [`if_/3`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27358600/4609915) together with the reified list-membership predicate [`memberd_t/3`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29963476/4609915) like so:

```
?-      if_(memberd_t(X,[1,2]), X=2, X=4).
X = 2 ; X = 4.
?- X=2, if_(memberd_t(X,[1,2]), X=2, X=4), X=2.
X = 2.
?-      if_(memberd_t(X,[1,2]), X=2, X=4), X=2.
X = 2 ; false.
?- X=4, if_(memberd_t(X,[1,2]), X=2, X=4), X=4.
X = 4.
?-      if_(memberd_t(X,[1,2]), X=2, X=4), X=4.
X = 4.
```

Correctness score 5/5. Efficiency score 4/5.

Answer (score 15):

I found this helpful for using an **if** statement in a rule.

```
max(X,Y,Z) :-
    (  X =< Y
    -> Z = Y
    ;  Z = X
    ).
```

Thanks to http://cs.union.edu/~striegnk/learn-prolog-now/html/node89.html

Answer (score 10):

There are essentially three different ways how to express something like if-then-else in Prolog. To compare them consider `char_class/2`. For `a` and `b` the class should be `ab` and `other` for all other terms. One could write this clumsily like so:

```
char_class(a, ab).
char_class(b, ab).
char_class(X, other) :-
   dif(X, a),
   dif(X, b).

?- char_class(Ch, Class).
   Ch = a, Class = ab
;  Ch = b, Class = ab
;  Class = other,
   dif(Ch, a), dif(Ch, b).
```

To write things more compactly, an if-then-else construct is needed. Prolog has a built-in one:

```
?- ( ( Ch = a ; Ch = b ) -> Class = ab ; Class = other ).
   Ch = a, Class = ab.
```

While this answer is sound, it is incomplete. Just the first answer from `( Ch = a ; Ch = b )` is given. The other answers are chopped away. Not very relational, indeed.

A better construct, often called a "soft cut" (don't believe the name, a cut is a cut is a cut), gives slightly better results (this is in YAP):

```
?- ( ( Ch = a ; Ch = b ) *-> Class = ab ; Class = other ).
   Ch = a, Class = ab
;  Ch = b, Class = ab.
```

Alternatively, SICStus has `if/3` with very similar semantics:

```
?- if( ( Ch = a ; Ch = b ), Class = ab , Class = other ).
   Ch = a, Class = ab
;  Ch = b, Class = ab.
```

So the last answer is still suppressed. Now enter `library(reif)` for Scryer, [SICStus](http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/ulrich/Prolog-inedit/sicstus/reif.pl), [YAP](http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/ulrich/Prolog-inedit/yap/reif.pl), and [SWI](http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/ulrich/Prolog-inedit/swi/reif.pl).  Install it and say:

```
?- use_module(library(reif)).

?- if_( ( Ch = a ; Ch = b ), Class = ab , Class = other ).
   Ch = a, Class = ab
;  Ch = b, Class = ab
;  Class = other,
   dif(Ch, a), dif(Ch, b).
```

Note that all the `if_/3` is compiled away to a wildly nested if-then-else for

```
char_class(Ch, Class) :-
   if_( ( Ch = a ; Ch = b ), Class = ab , Class = other ).
```

which expands in YAP 6.3.4 to:

```
char_class(A,B) :-
   (  A\=a ->
      (  A\=b ->
         B=other
      ;  A==b ->
         B=ab
      ;  A=b,
         B=ab
      ;  dif(A,b),
         B=other
      )
   ;  A==a ->
      B=ab
   ;  A=a,
      B=ab
   ;  dif(A,a),
      (  A\=b ->
         B=other
      ;  A==b ->
         B=ab
      ;  A=b,
         B=ab
      ;  dif(A,b),
         B=other
      )
   ).
```

Answer (score 4):

The best thing to do is to use the so-called `cuts`, which has the symbol `!`.

```
if_then_else(Condition, Action1, Action2) :- Condition, !, Action1.  
if_then_else(Condition, Action1, Action2) :- Action2.
```

The above is the basic structure of a condition function.

To exemplify, here's the `max` function:

```
max(X,Y,X):-X>Y,!.  
max(X,Y,Y):-Y=<X.
```

I suggest reading more documentation on cuts, but in general they are like breakpoints.
Ex.: In case the first `max` function returns a true value, the second function is not verified.

PS: I'm fairly new to Prolog, but this is what I've found out.

Comment: Not sure why this post was voted down. cold cuts are the most powerful way to handle conditions in prolog.

Comment: @gaurav.singharoy: What are "cold cuts"? W.r.t to Prolog, indeed.

Comment: That `max(X,Y,X):-X>Y,!.` should be setting the 3rd arg *after* the cut, to be steadfast - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39191184/steadfastness-definition-and-its-relation-to-logical-purity-and-termination

Comment: @brebs never have I ever thought this post would have received a comment 10 years from its original posting... cheers =D

Answer (score 3):

Prolog program actually is big condition for "if" with "then" which prints "Goal is reached" and "else" which prints "No sloutions was found". `A, B`means "A is true and B is true", most of prolog systems will not try to satisfy "B" if "A" is not reachable (i.e. `X=3, write('X is 3'),nl` will print 'X is 3' when X=3, and will do nothing if X=2).

Answer (score 3):

```
(  A == B ->
     writeln("ok")
;
     writeln("nok")
),
```

The else part is required

Comment: It is certainly a good idea to indicate an else-part, but it is not required.

Answer (score 2):

You should read [Learn Prolog Now! Chapter 10.2 Using Cut](http://www.learnprolognow.org/lpnpage.php?pagetype=html&pageid=lpn-htmlse44).  This provides an example:

`max(X,Y,Z)  :-  X  =<  Y,!,  Y  =  Z.`

to be said,

`Z` is equal to `Y` **IF** `!` is true (which it always is) **AND** `X` is `<= Y`.