# Call a predicate if another predicate failed

Tags: prolog

How can I call a predicate if all calls to another predicate failed?

I have:

```
foo(A, B, C, D) :-
    (bar1(Y,Z); bar2(L, K, M)),
    foo(A, B, C, D).
```

What I want :

- at any time, If `bar1/2` has succeded, `bar2/3` will never be executed.
- if all `bar1/2` calls failed, then `bar2/3` will eventually be executed.

Sample Backtracting tree

```
            root                                           root                 
                                                            |
           /   \                                            |
          /     \          all bar1 failed                  |
         /       \                                          |
        / | \     \        ===>>>======>>>>                 |
       /  |  \     \                                        |
      F   F  F     F                                        E
time  0   1  2     3                                        4 

Abbreviation:
       Bar1 failed : F
       Bar2 executed : E
```

Comment: I guess you are looking for "if bar1 then true else bar2". The rest should be easy with the answer to your previous question...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for what's known as "soft cut",

```
A *-> B ; C.
```

This is equivalent to `(A,B) ; (\+A,C)`: if `A` succeeds at least once, the above is equivalent to `A,B`. If not, it's equivalent to just `C`. The goal `A` is not retried.

Simple `if` construct allows the test predicate to succeed only once:

```
A -> B ; C.
```

is equivalent <sup>(almost - see you manual for details)</sup> to  `(once(A),B) ; (\+A,C)`, except that the goal `A` isn't retried.

Thus your case shall be

```
foo(A, B, C, D) :-
    (bar1(Y,Z) *-> true ; bar2(L, K, M)),
    foo(A, B, C, D).
```

***addition:*** Some Prolog implementations might not have this construct `*->` available (e.g. gprolog). In that case I see two possibilities. Either

```
(A , B) ; (\+A , C)
```

although it would retry `A`, or (writing `goal(X)` for A)

```
bagof(g(X), goal(X), L) -> ( member(g(X), L), B ) ; C
```

Of course the order of side-effects will be changed by this. The name `L` of the variable should be chosen such that it does not appear free in `B`.

Comment: When I have tried your comment on gprolog, it gives syntax error. Are there any way, I can catch same effect ?

Comment: I guess you can write that equivalent code, `(A,B) ; (\+A,C)`. It just will re-try `A`, so any side-effects will occur twice.

Comment: Or try this `( bagof(g(Y,Z), bar1(Y,Z), L) -> member(g(Y,Z),L) , true ; bar2(L,K,M) ), foo(A,B,C,D)`. Works in SWI Prolog. `true` is there just as a placeholder; it isn't needed by itself.

Comment: Sorry for late reply, I have tried *->, but gprolog cannot compile it. I do not understand why.

Comment: what is bagof ? Is it built in feature or Is it declared by you ? ( I could not found any explanation in google )

Comment: @gcc it's in [the manual](http://www.gprolog.org/manual/html_node/gprolog033.html), although I prefer [SWI documentation](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=bagof/3).

Comment: (A,B) ; ( \+ A, C)  === > infinite loop

Comment: I know that A,b,C are just place holder. For your second advice ( bagoff ), How can I  change it to my case ? ( I am using bar(X,Y), bar1(X,Y) ) . What should I write the place which is holded by L  ?

Comment: @gcc `( bagof( g(X,Y), ( bar(X,Y),bar1(X,Y) ) , L) -> (member(g(X,Y),L), stuff) ; otherstuff )`. "stuff" will be tried for each solution binding of `X,Y` of the conjunction `( bar(X,Y),bar1(X,Y) )`. "otherstuff" will be tried if there were no solutions for the conjunction. "stuff" should ***not*** have any free variable named L.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/12245/discussion-between-gcc-and-will-ness)  I have some misunderstand. Can you help me ?

Comment: What you *really* want is `if_/3`, not `(*->)/2`!

Comment: @repeat yes, `if_` seems a very important development. do you know about some paper or blog entry about it?

Comment: Not yet, but soon. In the meantime, I'll write an answer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2849045/if-in-prolog.