# Optional binding in Prolog

Tags: prolog

Let's imagine a simple database of genealogy facts where `mother(M, C)` and `father(F, C)` denotes that `M`/`F` is the mother/father of child `C`.

I've written a rule to find known parents of a child (zero, one or both):

```
parents(C, M, F) :-
  (mother(M, C) -> true; true),
  (father(M, C) -> true; true).
```

which binds `M` and `F` if they are known and leaves them unbound otherwise.

It works fine, which means that for a set of facts:

```
mother(m1, c1).
father(f1, c1).
mother(m2, c2).
```

a call to `parents(c1, M, F)` returns:

```
M = m1,
F = f1.
```

while `parents(c2, M, F)` returns:

```
M = m2.
```

but the use of the arrow operators seems a little strange to me. Am I missing something basic? Can the `(X -> true ; true)` calls be avoided/simplified?

Any help appreciated.

Cheers,

Comment: you can use `once( (mother(M, C) ; true) )` and similarly for the father.

Comment: @WillNess Thanks for the comment but, unfortunately, by using `once` it suffers from the same _incompleteness_ issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prolog is a real down to earth programming language. It has a pure subset. *Both* have their place.

`once( (A ; true) )` is  the answer to the question "how can we simplify `(A -> true; true)`".

If you want more purity, you could write `(A *-> true ; true )` with the "soft cut" `*->` which admits *all*  solutions from the successful `A` and only switches to the unsuccessful branch in case `A` didn't produce *any*. See also e.g. [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10886186/849891) of mine for more discussion.

Another variant is `(A ; \+ A)`.

Comment: The `*->/2` control construct is found in CxProlog, ECLiPSe, Jekejeke Prolog, JIProlog, SWI-Prolog, and YAP. SICStus Prolog and YAP provide a `if/3` soft-cut built-in predicate.

Comment: Brilliant, thanks! In the end I'll use `*->` even if it still looks a little weird. `(A ; \+A)` gets complicated, too, and is more prone to typo errors. Overall, I'm glad I asked the question, so the _incompleteness_ error got spotted. Thanks to @mat again!

Answer (score 4):

From a logical perspective, a *major* mistake in this program is its **incompleteness**.

Consider for example the **most general query**:

```
?- parents(X, Y, C).
X = c1,
Y = m1.
```

So, *no solution* for `c2` is reported.

But such a solution exists, as can be seen with:

```
?- parents(c2, Y, C).
Y = m2.
```

So, *which is it*, is there a solution or not?

Such mistakes almost *invariably* arise if you use `(->)/2` and other constructs that violate *logical purity* of your code. Please see [logical-purity](/questions/tagged/logical-purity) for more information.

Hence, from a logical perspective, I can only recommend to *avoid* such constructs, since they defeat the primary advantage of a logic programming language to begin with: The ability to reason *logically* about your programs.

Instead, focus on a clear *description* of the relations you want to describe, and state the conditions that make them true. This will allow you to use your Prolog programs in a sensible way.

**EDIT**: I see you prefer a botched program. For this purpose, I recommend **`ignore/1`**. `ignore(Goal)` calls `Goal` as `once(Goal)`, and *succeeds*. You can use this to simplify your program and still ensure that it remains incomplete.

Comment: I see, thank you. Is there a way to code the correct `parents` rule that would return `M = m1, F = f1` and `M = m2`? Or it is against the logical-purity?

Comment: I think using `mother/2` and `father/2` alone (and maybe using more descriptive names, such as `mother_child/2`) ought to be sufficient, no? This nice descriptive nature is a major attraction of using Prolog in the first place.

Comment: The trouble is that the example I gave is a simplification of my real database and rules in which I need to return both "parents" if they exist or just one if the other is unknown... I'll think about it more and report here if I find a better approach.

Comment: You can easily write two clauses to express a disjunction!