# "Return" 0 if odd and same value if even in prolog

Tags: prolog

I'm new to prolog so the concept of unifying is still new, so bear with me.

I want something like:

```
pair(X,Y)
```

That works like this:

```
?- pair(4,Y).

Y = 4,

?- pair(3,Y).

Y = 0,
```

But I don't really know how to do this. I know you can use something like X mod 2 =:= 0 which is true or false, but I don't know how to make "if this than that" code in prolog's way.

Comment: Prolog predicates are about making logical statements. So you want `pair(X, 0)` to be true if.... something. And you want `pair(X, X)` to be true if.... something.

Comment: `Y #= (X+1) mod 2 * X.` using [tag:clpfd], or `Y is (X+1) mod 2 * X.` For an answer in general, see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37057721/772868).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways to express a conditional statement in Prolog, besides using CLPFD (Constraint Logic Programming over Finite Domains):

1) make several statements, one for each case you are considering, and let Prolog execution mechanism find the one that is appropriate:

```
pair(X,Y) :- even(X), !, Y = X. % 'if X is even then Y = X'
pair(_,0).                      % 'else Y = 0'
```

In the second case here the unification is implicit, but in the first case it is explicit.

The `_` symbol is a syntactic sugar for an 'anonymous variable', that is a variable for whose bindings we do not care and that we do not use.

The *cut operator* `!` is used in the first clause to tell Prolog that it should not try to find other solutions for the `Y` if the first clause succeeds (like, backtracking and trying the second clause):

```
% without cut                         | % with cut
?- pair(4,Y).                         | ?- pair3(4,Y).
                                      |
Y = 4 ? ;                             | Y = 4 ? ;
                                      |
Y = 0 ? ;  % <- wrong behaviour!      | no.
                                      |
no                                    |
```

2) use the `(Condition -> ThenStatement ; ElseStatement)` if-then-else construct:

```
pair(X,Y) :- (even(X) -> Y = X ; Y = 0).
```

No *cuts* are allowed in the `Condition` argument. The first solution of the `Condition` is used.

3) some systems have the `if/3` predicate, that is evaluated as `if(Condition,ThenStatement,ElseStatement)`:

```
pair(X,Y) :- if( even(X), Y = X, Y = 0).
```

No *cuts* are allowed in the `Condition` argument.